# lsass.exe starts maxing CPU after ASP.NET web app deployment

Tags: asp.net, deployment, windows-server-2003

After deploying a new build (mostly changed DLL's) of an ASP.NET web app the CPU on the server is now jumping to 100% every few seconds and the culprit is lsass.exe. Do you think that the deployment of the asp.net web app to the server and this problem are related? (or a coincidence that it happened at the same time?)

More info:

This is the first time that I've done the build on a Server 2008 x64 machine. Previous the builds were done on a Server 2003 x86 machine. Target is "Any CPU" so should work on either. Deployed to server is Server 2003 x86.

I've searched the web for more info on this and have confirmed that the process is lsass.exe (first character a lower case L and not an upper case i) so ruled out the virus version. Found some docs relating to a Server 2000 bug but doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually isolated the problem to an ASP forum running "under" that ASP.NET web app. Using the admin page on the forum I took the forum down and then brought it back up again and the problem disappeared. I find this very frustrating because the problem has now gone but I don't know what caused it and as such it could easily return.

I also installed [this Microsoft Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939268/) and rebooted this server but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the System and Application event logs for anything unusual?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - yes I had checked that but nothing unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated to use Active Directory role provider?  I've seen issues where enumerating groups to do role checking pegs the CPU and really slows down the app.  I actually implemented a customized provider that allowed me to specify a particular OU and set of groups that I actually care about to get around this issue.

Comment: I found a number of references to AD while trying to resolve this problem but I haven't done anything with AD - thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

The xperf tools distributed in the [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysperf/perftools.mspx) will tell you exactly what is usin CPU time or disk bandwith.  These tools are free and work on any retail build of WS2008 or Vista. [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysperf/perftools.mspx) is series of posts on the xperf tools from myself.